# Grunt how to resize only the last added image?

Tags: automation, gruntjs, frontend

this is my grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    responsive_images: {
      dev: {
        options: {
                  sizes: [{
                    name: 'small',
                    width: '30%',
                    quality: 30
                  },{
                    name: 'medium',
                    width: '50%',
                    quality: 50
                  },{
                    name: 'large',
                    width: '60%',
                    quality: 60
                  },{
                    name: 'compressed',
                    width: '100%',
                    quality: 50
                  }]
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: ['img/*.{gif,jpg,png}'],
          cwd: 'Sito/',
          dest: 'Sito/'
        }]
      }
    },
   watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['**/*.{gif,jpg,png}'],
                tasks: ['responsive_images'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                    event: ['changed']
                },
            } 
        }
  });

 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
 grunt.registerTask('default', ['responsive_images']);
 };
```

I want to resize only the last image added in the folder, how can I do that?
Right now when I add an image all the previous images are edited with responsive-images.

Thank you if you want to answer me! =)

Comment: I've found the option newFileOnly but don't know how to edit the code

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    responsive_images: {
      dev: {
        options: {
                  newFilesOnly: 'true',
                  sizes: [{
                    name: 'small',
                    width: '30%',
                    quality: 30
                  },{
                    name: 'medium',
                    width: '50%',
                    quality: 50
                  },{
                    name: 'large',
                    width: '60%',
                    quality: 60
                  },{
                    name: 'compressed',
                    width: '100%',
                    quality: 50
                  }],
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: ['img/*.{gif,jpg,png}'],
          cwd: 'Sito/',
          dest: 'Sito/img-resp/'
        }]
      }
    },
   watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['**/*.{gif,jpg,png}'],
                tasks: ['responsive_images'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                    event: ['added']
                },
            } 
        }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['responsive_images']);
};
```

Comment: event should be added, sorry